# Reciprocal Coordinates in discrete 2D Fourier

Tags: image-processing, image, discrete

Is there a way to obtain the transformation of coordinates along with the Fourier transformation of a discrete data set?

Say I have some pixelwise information

```
dat = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {21, 21}];
```

And I know that this information maps to an area of -8 m to 8 m in the real world.

```
coords = Table[Table[{x, y}, {x, -8, 8, 8/10}], {y, -8, 8, 8/10}];
```

Is there a way to use the Fourier Transformation and also obtain the reciprocal coordinates in [1/m]?

```
{fft, fftCoords} = Fourier[dat, PleaseAlsoConsiderThatEachPixelHasACoordinate -> coords]
```

I hope this brings my question across.

It seems kind of natural to have such functionality somewhere to ensure that the reciprocal coordinates are in line with the way the Fourier transformation is done. But somehow I couldn't find it.

PS: Also there is no tag "fourier" or "fourier-transformation" as if no one ever has a question on these fundamental matters and the tag-finding algorithm does not seem to find a tag that is somewhere close to this. I cant create new tags, because I don't have the reputation. Can someone please create some tag in this direction?

Comment: While there may be no tag for `Fourier` or `FourierTransform`, you can still use the search window and come up with lots of relevant posts.

Comment: FourierTransform does not take discrete data but rather expects an analytic function. I could not find anything relevant to may question by using the search window.

Comment: `Fourier[list]` finds the discreet FT, but I don't know whether it will be useful to your particular problem.

Comment: I know, In my example above, Fourier[dat] would give me the FT, but it will organize the pixel in a certain way. For example the information of the Fourier transformation that concerns k=0 contribution (or infinite wavelength, i.e wavelength the size of the input array) is placed in one of the corners. In other languages/ other implementations of discrete FTs, this information would be placed in the center.

Comment: So in each pixel in the Fourier[dat] there is information that corresponds to a wave of certain wavelength (i.e. certain k-vector) in the original image. What I would like to have is the information which k-vector belongs to which pixel, i.e. the reciprocal coordinates of each pixel in the FT.

Comment: In numpy, for example, there is a function called numpy.fft.fftfreq(n, d), which yields the sampling frequencies. In my example with n=21 and d=0.8 m this gives 
np.fft.fftfreq(21,0.8)

array([ 0.        ,  0.05952381,  0.11904762,  0.17857143,  0.23809524,
        0.29761905,  0.35714286,  0.41666667,  0.47619048,  0.53571429,
        0.5952381 , -0.5952381 , -0.53571429, -0.47619048, -0.41666667,
       -0.35714286, -0.29761905, -0.23809524, -0.17857143, -0.11904762,
       -0.05952381])
which can be used to reconstruct the reciprocal coordinates (also in 2Dimensions)

Answer (score 1):

So for now I use a manual Solution, but I'm not sure if the coordinates I generate really correspond to how mathematica generates the Fourier:

```
spacing = 0.8;
dimension = 256;
xmeasure = (dimension - 1)*spacing;
ymeasure = (dimension - 1)*spacing;
xfstep = 1/xmeasure;
yfstep = 1/ymeasure;
fx = xfstep*Join[Range[0, dimension/2], -dimension/2 + Range[1, dimension/2]];
fy = yfstep*Join[Range[0, dimension/2], -dimension/2 + Range[1, dimension/2]];
kVectors = Table[Table[{2*\[Pi]*fx[[nx]], 2*\[Pi]*fy[[ny]]}, {ny, dimension}], {nx, dimension}]
```